# converting object's value number to string not working properly

Tags: javascript

I have situation about converting number to string. In the function below. I am iterating the objects and trying to change value type of `plan_price`. it's working when I do console.log()

```
    bestPlanArrange(bridals){
        let plans = [];
        bridals.filter(item => {
            item.plans.filter(plan => {
                plans.push(plan);
            });
        })
        let obj = {}
        let planArr = [];
        plans.filter(item => {
            item.plan_price.toString()
            console.log(item.plan_price) // doesn't listen the code above not working. 
            console.log(item.plan_price.toString()) // it's working like this.
            planArr.push(item) // I want to push after covert.
        })
        if (planArr[0] != null && plans[0].plan_price != null) {
            obj = planArr[0];
        }
        return obj;
    },
```

Do I missing something or doing something wrong here?

Comment: Why are you calling `filter` when the function doesn't return a `true/false` value and you're not using the result? It seems like you're using it when you really mean `forEach`.

Comment: Please provide an [mcve].  This is not easy to test without sample input and a runnable snippet.

Comment: And if you're using it to create a new array with values for each element of the original array, you should use `.map()`.

Comment: `let planArr = plans.map(item => item.plan_price.toString())`

Comment: thank you for pointing those out. @Barmar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Calling `toString()` doesn't change the value in place. You have to assign the result back to a variable:

```
item.plan_price = item.plan_price.toString()
```